# Is it possible to connect one Eloqua instance to multiple SFDC orgs?

Tags: integration

So we are working on Eloqua integration with Salesforce.com, and the clients have more than one Salesforce.com orgs. Is it possible to connect one Eloqua instance to multiple SFDC orgs?

Comment: Can't speak for Eloqua but when we used Marketo, the answer was NO (ca. 2012). The vendor should know the answer to this - the issue is usually that the marketing system's database is designed to sync to one SFDC (or CRM) system as it has mapping tables between its own schema and the correpsonding SFDC schema and only one set of credentials to apply

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to have different SFDC users with credentials to each of the SFDC instances. You will also need to create External calls linked to each of the instances, and Eloqua's internal Queue will allow you to stack the calls, such as:

Update Lead - Unsubscribe System 1
Update Lead - Unsubscribe System 2
Update Contact - Unsubscribe System 1
Update Contact - Unsubscribe System 2

You then need to build duplicate Update CRM programs utilizing the specific call to the specific system. In addition, you will need programmatic logic that determines which Lead/Contact should get sent to which system.

On the inbound side, you'll want to make sure you map the SFDC IDs to distinct fields,  such as SFDC Lead ID - System 1 and SFDC Lead ID - System 2, and make sure your "GET" calls map to the right fields on the Eloqua Contact record.

With some diligence on your part, you can make it work!

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple CRM users to one instance of Eloqua. However, only one set of field mappings between Eloqua and a SFDC instance can be cached at a time. What that means is that if you wanted to add a field to CRM A that would sync with Eloqua, when you refreshed those fields, all of the external calls to CRM B would break because they would have refreshed/updated to the the fields in CRM A. You would then have to manually change those fields back over to CRM B and set up the external call again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please note that multiple CRM users in native integration are not officially supported.
2. The new Eloqua/SFDC Integration App was introduced to replace the native integration and it officially supports multiple CRMs: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAA/Help/Apps/SalesforceApp/SalesforceApp.htm